# Reading XML with inline schema in python

Tags: python, sql-server, xml

I have multiple XML files with Inline schema. I try to parse the xml data using python, but it does give me any result.

I want to get the values of the elements

ogrid_cde
role

from all ogridroles tags

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1" xmlns:schema="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd"/>
        <xsd:element name="ogridroles">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="ogrid_cde" type="sqltypes:int" nillable="1"/>
                    <xsd:element name="role" nillable="1">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:char" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="1"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
    <ogridroles xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1">
        <ogrid_cde>28</ogrid_cde>
        <role>T</role>
    </ogridroles>
    <ogridroles xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1">
        <ogrid_cde>75</ogrid_cde>
        <role>T</role>
    </ogridroles>
    <ogridroles xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1">
        <ogrid_cde>93</ogrid_cde>
        <role>O</role>
    </ogridroles>
    <ogridroles xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1">
        <ogrid_cde>135</ogrid_cde>
        <role>O</role>
    </ogridroles>
</root>
```

Python Code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('ogridroles.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for a in root.findall('{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1}ogridroles'):
    print (a.attrib)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('ogridroles.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    print(child[0].text, "==", child[1].text)
```

Thanks to Laughing Vergil for the clue

Comment: This Python library is working for small size cal file. But not for larger file size, I tested it with 35gb file size. It throws an error out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken, an `xmlns` value is returned as a **tag**, not as an **element**. Try checking for the tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

For large files, use lxml.etree.iterparse() in combination with the zipfile module to read directly from the compressed file. This returns an iterator that must be explicitly opened, preventing the whole file from being read into memory.

```
from lxml import etree
from zipfile import ZipFile

zipped_file = ZipFile(<your file>, 'r')
for event, element in etree.iterparse(zipped_file.open(<filename inside zip>)):
    for item in [ogrid_cde, role]:
        if item in element.tag:
            print('{}: {}'.format(item, element.text))
```

That should print out pairs of the field names (the item matched to the element tag) and the values (the text retrieved from the element).